# Append content at the end in Kendo editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

Some time is headache when working with new plugins like kenodo editor. In editor there is one method to append HTML element to editor, but it's normal behaviour is it append content at cursor position. To change this behaviour and customize that you want any content to be append at the end of editor.

Answer (score 0):

This type of customization can be acchived refer http://dojo.telerik.com/ApIFO/76

Here there is complete example showing how to append content at end of editor's last line no matter where your cursor lies.